# PHP echo displaying outside set html

Tags: php, html

I know this is something really simple but it is not working for me....

I am using the following to display a variable within html.

```
<?php if (!empty($data['title_text'])) {
    echo '<h1 class="site-title animated fadeInDown">' .$data['title_text']. '</h1>'; 
}
```

It is displaying but the varibale is not within the html element. It is displaying like so

```
TEST DATA
<h1 class="site-title animated fadeInDown"></h1>
```

Comment: Please provide the output of var_dump($data)

Comment: What encode do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable might contain characters that invalidate / mess with the html. You should always make sure that cannot happen:

```
echo '<h1 class="site-title animated fadeInDown">' . htmlspecialchars($data['title_text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</h1>';
```

(assuming you are using utf-8)

Comment: If you're using UTF-8 then htmlentities($data['title_text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') might be a better use, right?

Comment: @CBergau When not inside an html tag / property value I don't see how single quotes could do any harm and `utf-8` is the default from php 5.4 on. Anyway, it certainly won't hurt :-) Edited!

Comment: I wasn't mentioning htmlentites because of the quotes. Just wanted to point on the encoding :)

Comment: Actually i made i mistake here. The default value is already UTF-8  see http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php :-)

Comment: @CBergau No, see my previous comment, only since php 5.4, check the manual on the `encoding` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this add this part of code on your page:

```
define('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);
```